# Typescript prevent "sort imports" to affect one specific import

Tags: typescript

I am using the newest typescript option that automatically sort imports and remove unused ones.

The problem is, I use `react-hot-loader`. And it requires to do the `react-hot-loader` import *before* `react` import. Which goes against typescript rules :

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import * as React from 'react';
```

Is there any way to prevent typescript from organizing one specific import (or just ignore the file) ?

I could disable the setting whenever I have to edit the file which do such import. But this is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can extract the hot logic into a custom react component that wraps your `App` and does nothing else.

And never ever edit it again

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import * as React from 'react';
import { App } from './App';

class Hot extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <App />;
    }
}

export default hot(module)(Hot);
```